# Why doesn’t text-align: right; work? I write my text but it doesn't change its position to the right side

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

I've searched a lot but apparently it doesn't work. Just as fact, I am new and I don't want to be in tutorial hell, so I made a practice to write what I've learned, but I'm stuck with this:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Título del sitio web</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <h1 class="encabezado">Sitio web de App</h1>
        <a href="index.html" class="links ">Inicio</a>
        <a href="https://c.tenor.com/_4YgA77ExHEAAAAd/rick-roll.gif" class="links ">App</a>
        <a href="#" class="links ">Sobre nosotros</a>
    </div>

    <div class="foot">Todos los derechos reservados</div>

    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.encabezado {
    background: #007fff;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    padding: 30px;
}
.links{
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:inline-block; 
}

.foot{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #404040;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Question fixed.

Comment: The text within each anchor (a) element is aligned right, within that element. You probably want to put all the links into a parent element and then position that to the right of its parent div.

Answer (score 0):

You can just move the links to a new div and style the div to align to right. And for the rest of the link decoration, you can add them in a separate class under their `<a>` tags.

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.encabezado {
    background: #007fff;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    padding: 30px;
}

.linksDiv {
    text-align: right;
}

.links {
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.foot {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #404040;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Título del sitio web</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1 class="encabezado">Sitio web de App</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="linksDiv">
      <a class="links" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
      <a class="links" href="https://c.tenor.com/_4YgA77ExHEAAAAd/rick-roll.gif">App</a>
      <a class="links" href="#">Sobre nosotros</a>
    </div>
    <div class="foot">Todos los derechos reservados</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.